# How do I prevent my web browser from opening on hawtio startup?

Tags: hawtio

I start hawtio in a Windows command shell like so...

```
java -jar hawtio-app-1.4.59.jar
```

...however, when it is about to complete its initialisation, Internet Explorer opens on my Windows PC with the hawtio welcome page http://localhost:8080/hawtio/welcome.

How do I tell hawtio to not open a browser on startup?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the jar with `--help` option where it outputs what commands it takes.

But we should add an option to not open the browser, so you can turn that off. I logged a ticket: https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/issues/2095

So currently you cannot but when that ticket is implement then you can turn if off.

**update**

I found that we added a JVM system property you can use to turn it off,

So you can run with

```
java -jar hawtio-app-1.4.59.jar -Dhawtio.openUrl=false
```

But we would still add a nice option as well.

Comment: Thanks for the update, works perfectly. One minor correction, the JVM arg goes after java: java -Dhawtio.openUrl=false -jar hawtio-app-1.4.59.jar